# Custom background color for Material-UI menu

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm new to material-ui. I tried adding the menu component into my project and I was able to display it. The menu's background was white and black text color. I want to change the colors to match my application.

I copied the working component code from this link - http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu

I've been adding backgroundColor to different parts of my style object but no luck

```
import React from 'react';
import Menu from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/lib/menus/menu-item';
import Divider from 'material-ui/lib/divider';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/lib/font-icon';
import ContentCopy from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/content-copy';
import ContentLink from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/content/link';
import Delete from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/action/delete';
import Download from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/file/file-download';
import PersonAdd from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/social/person-add';
import RemoveRedEye from 'material-ui/lib/svg-icons/image/remove-red-eye';

const style = {
  menu: {
    marginRight: 32,
    marginBottom: 32,
    float: 'left',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 0,
    width: 235,
  },
  rightIcon: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    lineHeight: '24px',
  },
  bg: {
    backgroundColor: '#364150',
    color: 'white'
  }
};

const MenuExampleIcons = () => (
  <div style={style.bg}>
    <Menu autoWidth={false} style={style.menu}>
      <MenuItem primaryText="Preview" leftIcon={<RemoveRedEye />} />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Share" leftIcon={<PersonAdd />} />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Get links" leftIcon={<ContentLink />} />
      <Divider />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Make a copy" leftIcon={<ContentCopy />} />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Download" leftIcon={<Download />} />
      <Divider />
      <MenuItem primaryText="Remove" leftIcon={<Delete />} />
    </Menu>
  </div>
);

export default MenuExampleIcons;
```

Comment: Looks like it might be covered here: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette

Comment: I clicked on that link and then went to UI Color application and I got here http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette. I am not sure why I am seeing android. I'm not working on an android application.

Comment: I went to your link again. I read it but unfortunately, that page doesn't really help at all.

Comment: There are themes to download

Comment: I got it working last night by putting it in getChildContext() { ...} I also learned that it will only affect the element where you have the overriding code. It will not affect the other material-ui elements on other components.

Answer (score 10):

You would have to add a style object to each of your menu items as well.

```
<MenuItem key={item.key} value={value} style={{backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white'}} primaryText={item.name}/>
```

Comment: Works, and what i did initially, but breaks mouse-over/hover functionality

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a fairly older post, what isn't new to React and Material UI, right? So here is my solution in case anyone comes across this.

```
div[role="menu"] > div > span {
    background: red !important;
    color: white !important;
}
```

Keep in mind, this will affect ALL of your menus. But that isn't necessarily a bad thing for consistency purposes. If you want to have different menus then you'll have to style each and every individual menu item in each menu. This is by far the most ridiculous thing Materieal UI has done yet. So I'm hoping Material Next will have a better fix